# C# XML parse with xmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I couldn't do a lot while trying to read XML. I'm a beginner in C#, I want to parse the following XML using a `XmlTextReader` as an example.

I take p1 and p2, but I couldn't reach p24 and p26. How should I proceed?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Products>
      <Books>
        <pb>
          <p1>1</p1>
          <p2>2</p2>
          <p24>
            <a>
              <a1>97924</a1>
              <a2>Fabio Moon</a2>
            </a>
            <a>
              <a1>82056</a1>
              <a2>Gabriel Ba</a2>
            </a>
          </p24>
          <p26>
            <ca>
              <ca1>001005</ca1>
              <ca2>Çocuk Kitapları</ca2>
              <ca3>
                <ca1>001005016</ca1>
                <ca2>Roman</ca2>
              </ca3>
              <ca3>
                <ca1>001005017</ca1>
                <ca2>Öykü</ca2>
              </ca3>        
            </ca>
          </p26>
        </pb>
      </Books>
    </Products>
```

C#:

```
while (xmlTextReader.Read())
{                   
    if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlTextReader.Name == "p1")
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(xmlTextReader.Value); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the code is only looking for the `p1` element (`xmlTextReader.Name == "p1"` in the if condition).

I modified the code from [XmlTextReader Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader.read?view=netframework-4.8#examples) to suit your needs.  If you want to get the text values too you need to check whether the node is type `XmlNodeType.Text`.  Then you can use `xmlTextReader.Name` to get the tag name and use `xmlTextReader.Text` to get the inner text.

If you only want to read children of the `<pb>` element then you can use `ReadToDescendant`.

The code below should read your whole xml and print it to the console:

```
// read to 'pb' element and then read it's children
xmlTextReader.ReadToDescendant("pb");
while (xmlTextReader.Read())
{
    switch (xmlTextReader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            Console.WriteLine("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='uft-8'?>");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            Console.WriteLine("<{0}>", xmlTextReader.Name);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            Console.WriteLine(xmlTextReader.Value);
            break;            
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            Console.WriteLine("</{0}>", xmlTextReader.Name);
            break;
    }
}
// remember to close the reader
if (xmlTextReader != null)
    xmlTextReader.Close();
```